# Reading 'uint8' faster in matlab than reading 'double'?

Tags: matlab, io, fread

I am trying to improve the performance of my large disk read operations.

[Apparently, reading in `uint8` and then typecasting to double is faster than reading directly in `double`.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/350886-is-it-possible-to-improve-fread-fwrite-performance-and-further-speed-up-loading-writing-of-binary-da)

I have tried to reproduce this, but I am getting the same performance with `double` and `uint`. Here is my code for both cases. What am I doing wrong?

```
N=16800; %my matrices are quite large

%the file contains a 1 x N^2 double vector
fid = fopen('myfile.bin', 'r');

%using *uint and casting
tic
matrix1=fread(fid,8*N^2, '*uint8');
matrix1=typecast(matrix1,'double');
toc

%using double straight away
tic
matrix2=fread(fid,N^2,'double');
toc

fclose(fid);
```

The timings are practically the same. Why would uint8 be faster anyway?

```
Elapsed time is 1.975456 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.077142 seconds.
```

Edit: As @Rahnema1 pointed out, the above example has a bug. `fseek` should be used to return to the beginning of the file. 
Edit: As @Cris Luengo pointed out, the link makes that suggestions for files that contain mixed data types, so this is not applicable to my case.

Comment: Note that `fread` positions the file pointer after the last value read so if you want to read from the beginning of the file you should set the file pointer at the origin `fseek(fid,0,0);`

Comment: That link contains a comment that says to read the whole file as uint8, then parse it. This is to avoid repeated calls to `fread` for reading values of different types. You are reading the whole file in one go, it doesn’t matter what type you read it in, it won’t go any faster than this.